# How safe are cable cars?

Tags: safety, statistics, gondolas-and-cable-cars

I was travelling from Singapore main land to Sentosa island using cable car. I never had problem flying or even skydiving. This cable car thing just didn't make me feel safe, I was literally terrified. Riding it many times didn't solve the problem :/

**Q: How safe are cable cars? any statistics?**

[image: cable car]
[image: cable car]

Comment: What's safe enough? Better than 50-50??

Comment: 99.9999% might work for me ;)

Comment: What I mean is - your question says "are cable cars safe enough?" - to which an answer would be simply "yes" since governments let them get built.  So I'm wondering what you expect as an answer?

Comment: changed it @MarkMayo

Comment: Just check it there is no US air base anywhere near :-P

Comment: Governments also close them down so with this logic the simple answer would also be "no".

Comment: I've changed the tag since "cable car" has two very distinct meanings and ambiguous words make bad tag names. In fact I've added "gondolas" to the tag name. This word also has two distinct meanings but taken together there's only one shared meaning.

Comment: You've obviously never been skiing...

Comment: @TylerAndFriends I live in Saudi Arabia.. unless you mean sand skiing then No.

Comment: Haha I see!  I just meant that if you had been skiing before, you would be a little more used to the feeling of being suspended in the air in a little capsule while swinging back and forth and having no control over any of it.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends ythat no control over it feeling is the worse ever...

Comment: Specifically, for the Singapore Cable Car that links Singapore island to Sentosa island, 7 people were killed in 1983 when an oil rig struck the cables. <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Cable_Car_disaster>

Comment: Even after reading the answers, I am terrified of these when they are held by a single cable. I've seen some with 2 and that seems at least a redundancy.... otherwise it's one cable snap away from ALL the cable cars falling.

Comment: I guess that's changed now since the [events of this morning](https://apnews.com/article/italy-cable-car-84672bf7fcd99f103587cc3862b49dcc).

Comment: @Kay  Not really. That would be like saying that Cars, Trains, Ships, Airplanes or even an horse drawn buggy are not save becase one accident has occurred. The main reason that the report from Italy is in the news is because it happens so seldom. Or have I missed **thousands** of news reports reporting deadly car accidents that occur each month?

Comment: @Itai you are aware that pretty much all cables are actually braided from hundreds or thousands of smaller strands, right?  So in that aspect, they all have significant redundancy built in thats already much better than having a second cable...

Comment: @Moo - Not really. If the whole thing snaps, it doesn't matter how many strands are each cable made of, anything that  breaks the cable or the mechanism that holds that one cable could break and would not have redundancy

Comment: @Itai “if the whole thing snaps” - thats the issue Im raising.  With a second cable, all you are doing is increasing the number of strands, so if something has broken all the strands in the first cable then....

Comment: @Moo - It's completely different. It's like comparing RAID-1 that runs two disks vs storing all files twice in a single disk! Yeah, it's better than nothing but having two separate cables means that the strands in one cable are not related to those in the other. Imagine if a tree fell and knock out a cable, even if you double its strands it would snap and the result would be very different than two cables. The issue is that all strands on one cable are dependent and anything that is harming a cable would pressure at its strands.

Comment: @Itai I disagree - this is a cable car, there aren't any alternative routes the cables can take, so if a tree was to fall and hit one cable the second cable is also going.  And (aside from your example making no sense) no one should use RAID1 these days, the BER of modern spinny disks is way way way too low for anything but RAID6 or above (you are significantly more likely to run into a second failure while rebuilding an array in RAID1 or RAID5 these days purely because of the inherent error rates and huge sizes - https://www.digistor.com.au/the-latest/Whether-RAID-5-is-still-safe-in-2019/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Firstly, it depends on the 'cable car' meaning - I take it you mean the ones hanging above the ground, instead of the [San Francisco-style ones which were named one of the most dangerous forms of transportation around](http://www.nelsonbarry.com/personal-injury/cable-cars-named-one-of-the-most-dangerous-forms-of-mass-transit/).

So on to the type you're talking about.  Safety regulations will surely differ in every country.  However, since many are made in Switzerland and exported elsewhere (including the 50 and 100-person gondola at Grouse Mountain in Vancouver), I've found [some statistics out of Switzerland](http://gondolaproject.com/2011/10/19/are-gondolas-and-cable-cars-safe/):

For every 1000 passengers in 2008, there were 0.000005 deaths. If I'm doing my maths correctly, that is one in every 200,000,000 passengers, or a 99.9999995% non-death carry rate :)

In 2009, same chart - there were no deaths.

The same page looks at the deaths in rail, trolleybus and other forms of transportation, all of which have a higher accident and death rate. So basically, if you're willing to get into a method of transportation on the ground, statistically, you're safer off travelling by gondola/cable-car :)

Comment: For context, how does the 2008 number compare to air travel?

Comment: @DanNeely no idea, only found the stats for ground-based travel.  Generally you're not considering flight for the distances that cable cars / gondolas travel.

Comment: I'm thinking that the question is not amount of fatalities per passenger, but the number of accidents per ride. Some accidents are non-fatal, while some (few) have several fatalities. This isn't shown in the table in your source, though.

Comment: @Nix These statistics are generally not measured in accidents per ride, as each gondola may carry different numbers of passengers.  It's far more common to measure per x number of persons, as then you can work out the chances for an individual.

Comment: @DanNeely - Air travel is roughly comparable, at around the 1-in-100-million mark: speaking purely in terms of "proper" airlines, not some bloke flying a Cessna around in fog over his farm

Comment: FYI, the link in your 2nd paragraph is now obsolete.

Comment: The link in your first paragraph (SF cable cars) is also dead.